# Tilde (~) in Mac OSX terminal pathway

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I am new to the Mac OSX environment, and was programming in C using the terminal. To change the current directory, I used the command `cd ..` to go one level up. However, this had a weird effect on the terminal. A clear screen on my mac terminal used to show this path always-

```
manishs-mbp:manishgiri$
```

However, since the time I did `cd ..`(to go one level up), the current pathway of the terminal has changed to:

```
manishs-mbp:~ manishgiri$
```

As you can see, there is a tilde now in the pathname. On reading about it, it looks like this tilde is used to represent the home directory in mac OS. However, I would like to get rid of it, as it was earlier.

Could you please provide a way to do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

**EDIT- Adding more information**

I tried to think of it, and realized that `cd ..` would have taken me one level up. So, I entered `pwd`in the terminal to see the current pathway (this is with the tilde situation), and got this-

```
manishs-mbp:~ manishgiri$ pwd
/Users/manishgiri
```

Maybe the tilde appears because I am now by default in the /Users(Home) folder. If that's the case, then how do I revert it back to the previous settings to get rid of the tilde?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In virtually all modern Unix shells, `~` is shorthand for your home directory. On OS X, this expands to `/Users/accountname`, in most Linuxes it will be `/home/accountname`.

The shell you are using (presumably BASH) has its prompt configured to show the current working directory's basename. For instance, if you were to `cd Downloads`, you'll likely see your prompt change to:
`manishs-mbp:Downloads manishgiri$`

If you don't want to see your current directory in your BASH prompt, you'll need to edit your prompt. You can see your current prompt configuration by running:
`echo $PS1`
You'll likely get a response of:
`\h:\W \u\$`

The `\W` indicates the Basename of your current directory (e.g. `~` or `Downloads`), you need to get that out of the prompt.

At the most basic, to remove the path just run:
`PS1="\h \u\$"`

If you want the change to be permanent, you'll need to change/create the PS1 variable declaration in your shell's config file (i.e. `.bashrc`). You'll likely want to read the BASH manual pages or spend some time with a search engine if you want more information on BASH prompt customization.

That said, if you're new to the terminal, I suggest leaving it as-is. It's actually quite helpful to have your working directory displayed in your prompt and saves you from having to constantly run `pwd`. To each their own though.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I'm overthinking it and you just want a simple (possibly hacky) way to make your prompt not have the working directory basename. If so:
`echo 'PS1="\h:\u\$" >> ~/.bashrc`
then open a new Terminal window.